# Implement a counter in etcd API?

Tags: concurrency, etcd

Any suggestions for implementing a shared distributed counter in etcd using the API? I imagine I can create a lock that that manages a KV. But is there a different "best practice" way to do this in etcd?

Comment: The etcd repo has [contributed recipes](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/contrib/recipes/queue.go) that might be useful.